# Using command line to redirect inputs and outputs

Tags: linux

The following works and will convert `/tmp/file.docx` to `/tmp/file.pdf`.

```
libreoffice3.5. --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp /tmp/file.docx
```

How would I convert https://www.mysite.com/getfile.php?id=123 (which will return a docx file) and save it as `/tmp/file_123.pdf`?  I would expect it would require wget, piping, and input/output redirecting.

Thank you

EDIT - RESPONSE TO zebediah49's Post

```
> libreoffice3.5 --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp <(wget -O - "http://www.mysite.com/demo/lib/m.php?cid=9&controller=detail&task=displayDocument&id=56&x=fc872c033770e3bc8706e6a90bcdff02")

--2012-07-03 14:09:03--  http://www.mysite.com/demo/lib/m.php?cid=9&controller=detail&task=displayDocument&id=56&x=fc872c033770e3bc8706e6a90bcdff02
Resolving www.mysite.com... 99.999.999.999
Connecting to www.mysite.com|99.999.999.999|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 29696 (29K) [application/msword]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

     0K .......... .......... .........                       100% 14.2M=0.002s

2012-07-03 14:09:03 (14.2 MB/s) - `-' saved [29696/29696]
```

EDIT - RESPONSE TO rekire's first solution

```
> wget http://www.mysite.com/demo/lib/m.php?cid=9&controller=detail&task=displayDocument&id=56&x=fc872c033770e3bc8706e6a90bcdff02 --no-check-certificate -O /tmp/file.docx
--2012-07-03 14:34:12--  http://www.mysite.com/demo/lib/m.php?cid=9
Resolving www.mysite.com... bash: --no-check-certificate: command not found
99.999.999.999
Connecting to www.mysite.com|99.999.999.999|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1236 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `m.php?cid=9.8'

     0K .                                                     100% 42.1M=0s

2012-07-03 14:34:12 (42.1 MB/s) - `m.php?cid=9.8' saved [1236/1236]

> libreoffice3.5 --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp /tmp/file.docx
```

EDIT - RESPONSE TO rekire's second solution

```
> TMPFILE=`mktemp -u`
> wget http://www.mysite.com/demo/lib/m.php?cid=9&controller=detail&task=displayDocument&id=56&x=fc872c033770e3bc8706e6a90bcdff02 --no-check-certificate -O $TMPFILE
--2012-07-03 14:24:09--  http://www.mysite.com/demo/lib/m.php?cid=9
Resolving www.mysite.com... bash: --no-check-certificate: command not found
99.999.999.999
Connecting to www.mysite.com|99.999.999.999|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1236 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `m.php?cid=9.5'

     0K .                                                     100% 42.1M=0s

2012-07-03 14:24:09 (42.1 MB/s) - `m.php?cid=9.5' saved [1236/1236]


> libreoffice3.5 --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp $TMPFILE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your command this two lines should work:

```
wget https://www.mysite.com/getfile.php?id=123 --no-check-certificate -O /tmp/file.docx
libreoffice3.5. --headless --convert-to pdf:outfile.pdf --outdir /tmp /tmp/file.docx
```

Or like zebediah49 said with a unique filename:

```
TMPFILE=`mktemp -u`
wget https://www.mysite.com/getfile.php?id=123 --no-check-certificate -O $TMPFILE
libreoffice3.5. --headless --convert-to pdf:outfile.pdf --outdir /tmp $TMPFILE
```

**Please note:** The outfile will be overwritten in every run so you should use also unique names for the output file.

Comment: I would like to add that one should use `mktemp` to avoid accidents.

Comment: @zebediah49 Nice hint I didn't know that command yet.

Comment: Thanks rekire,  TTesting as we speak.  I didn't mean to show as https.  Just get rid of the "--no-check-certificate"?

Comment: Of cause you can omit that. That parameter is just to avoid trouble with for wget unknown ca certificates.

Comment: Rekire,  Can't seem to figure out where the file is going.  Below is the server's response to both your solutions.  Any ideas?  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: When Googling, get rid of the 3.5.  It is an open source version of Microsoft Office.  I'm just using part of it's library to convert DOC, DOCX, XLS, and XLSX documents to PDFs.

Comment: I know that was also known as open office... still trying to find docs about the parameters... I found something [here](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters): *--convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir output_dir] files*. So if I guess right you need to add `:myoutfile.pdf`

Comment: It appears you stumbled upon the same docs as I did.. I think that `output_filter_name` is the internal filter name (such as `writer_pdf_Export` or whatever), not a file name.  I can't find a way to specify a file name when using that though.  I think a non-batch command that does an 'open/saveAs/close' would be better, but I'm not positive how to do it.

Comment: Your solution works, except you had a typo in your wget (should be wget -O filename url)
@zebediah49.  I like your solution the most since it doesn't need to temporarily store the .docx document only if it worked :)
Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want one line, you can use redirection to do

```
libreoffice3.5. --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp <(wget -O - "https://www.mysite.com/getfile.php?id=123")
```

EDIT:

I was afraid libreoffice might not allow a save name when using `--convert-to`.  If you prefer, here's a version that will use a temporary directory, but save the output in the current one (I assume you don't want to dig through /tmp to find your stuff...

```
TEMP_DIR=`mktemp -d`
wget -P "$TEMP_DIR" "https://www.mysite.com/getfile.php?id=123"
libreoffice3.5. --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir ./ "$TEMD_DIR/*"
rm -r "$TEMP_DIR"
```

I'm formatting it as if it was to be in a script.. if you're just running it yourself you can know that you won't be clobbering anything and/or do everything in your current directory, and thus just use

```
wget "https://www.mysite.com/getfile.php?id=123"
libreoffice3.5. --headless --convert-to pdf "getfile.php?id=123"
```

Comment: What's the difference between `<()` and a pipe `|` ?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html explains it better, but to summarize, the process substitution idiom lets you use pipes with programs that insist on accepting input from a file.  I didn't know if libreoffice would accept stdin for the input file, so I chose that syntax.

Comment: So it's like piping into stdin and also passing `/dev/fd/0` as a command-line argument, except it will use a different fd number.  Neat!  +1

Comment: Thank you zebediah49,  I tried your solution, and it seems to work, but I can figure out where it is saving the file.  I posted the response under my original post as I do not know how to neatly do so under the comments.  Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like the reason I can't find it is because the file doesn't have a name.  You can specify what directory you want by including --outdir /your/desired/directory (and if blank, uses current directory), but cannot specify the desired output file name as it will only automatically take the input file name.  But the wget input doesn't have a name.  Hoping to force the name to be "file_123.pdf".